# Read a png file located in the same package as the tests, for image comparision using Sikuli

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I did not want to hard code the complete path to images directory and this is the code I have :

```
InputStream BaseImage = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/images/image1.png");


        try{

            Pattern image = new Pattern(String.valueOf(BaseImage));
            image.similar((float)0.99);
            Screen screen=new Screen();
            screen.wait(image, 10);
            Match match = screen.find(image);
            Assert.assertTrue(match.getScore() < 10);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail();

        }
    }
```

This is the absolute path - /Users/xxxx/xxxx/selenium/src/test/java/com/lexus/systemtests/images/image1.png I am trying to modify.

The error message I see while running my Selenium tests is :

FindFailed: ImageFile null not found on disk
  Line 1671, in file Region.java

```
at org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:1671)
at com.lexus.systemtests.pages.SikuliTest.screenimage_has_to_match_saved_image(SikuliTest.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:35)
at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:12)
at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:31)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:35)
at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:38)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:289)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:116)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:120)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:108)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:26)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

I think the script is not able to find the image directory. Can you please let me know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use a debugger or a `println()` statement to see what `getResource(path)` returns. Then you can tell if the URL is to the correct directory and, if not, how to adjust it.

If I'm not mistaken, the normal case is to call `getResource()` or `getResourceAsStream()` on the *class* object, not its class loader. E.g. `SikuliTest.class.getResource("/images/image1.png")`. This might not make a difference.

You might need to pass it a relative path (one that doesn't begin with a `/`) if you want it to look in the test class's package.

```
Pattern image = new Pattern(String.valueOf(BaseImage));
```

I assume that `Pattern` is a Selenium class, not `java.util.regex.Pattern`. This line of code does not like a workable way to read an image from an InputStream, but I don't know what the `Pattern()` constructor requires.

[Finally, there's a strong Java naming convention for starting class names with an upper case letter and variable names with a lower case letter. Thus `BaseImage` should be `baseImage` or `baseImageStream`. This convention exists because `.` is heavily overloaded, so the naming convention keeps aPackage.AClass distinct from AClass.aVariable.]